# What is the UK law about the child born in the UK of an Indonesian citizen?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, children

I'm an Indonesian single mother with a daughter. I live in in the UK, and have a domestic worker visa. I'll be getting ILR in April. My child was born in the UK and is nearly 2 years old. She has an Indonesian passport and has a visa as my dependent, which will expire on 1 July 2017.

I have left her in Indonesia for the moment, and without her father's permission, because I couldn't support her by myself here. I didn't receive any support from her father, who is illegal in the UK, and I'm not entitled to any benefits.

Am I committing a crime by doing all this? When would be the best time to bring her back to the UK?

Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: I really think you should seek help of a solicitor for that matter, as this issue is rather complex and there is a lot at stake. You may be eligible for legal aid, please check here: https://www.gov.uk/check-legal-aid